# Is there a difference between GuildMemberManager.resolve() and Guild.member() in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

[`Guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) returns the [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) form of a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object, if the user is present in the guild. It takes a [`UserResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/UserResolvable) as a parameter (user ID or object).

[`GuildMemberManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=resolve) resolves a [`GuildMemberResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/GuildMemberResolvable) to a GuildMember object. What confused me is that a `GuildMemberResolvable` can be either a GuildMember object or a `UserResolvable`.

First of all, why would anybody need to convert a GuildMember object into a GuildMember object?

Seconds of all, besides the option of resolving a GuildMember object as well as a `UserResolvable`, is there any difference between the two methods? They look exactly the same to me.

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first(); // a user object
const guild = message.client.guilds.cache.get('Guild ID'); // a guild object

guild.member(user); // a guildmember object
guild.members.resolve(user); // also a guildmember object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods are identical.

The [source for `Guild#member`](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/7ec0bd93b0d7788e8ccf5576add37f7198be3f72/src/structures/Guild.js#L646-L648) shows that it simply calls `GuildMemberManager#resolve`:

```
  member(user) {
    return this.members.resolve(user);
  }
```

`UserResolvable` and `GuildMemberResolvable` are also the same. `UserResolvable` can be a `User`, `Snowflake`, `Message`, or `GuildMember`; and a `GuildMemberResolvable` can be a `GuildMember` or `UserResolvable`. In this way, the type `GuildMemberResolvable` is essentially redundant and could be substituted for `UserResolvable`.

```
// Using TypeScript syntax to show the types
type UserResolvable = User | Snowflake | Message | GuildMember

// same as GuildMember | User | Snowflake | Message
type GuildMemberResolvable = GuildMember | UserResolvable
```